# No Logo appearing on my splash screen ,Also Preview not showing up for XML

Tags: android

Iam currently Working  with Splash Screen ,My code Runs Fine but
1.When I launch App the Logo is not showing.
2. Preview is not showing in my background_splashscreen.xml

**background_splashscreen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/white" />
- <item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/logo" android:gravity="center" />
</item>

</layer-list>
```

**splashscreen.java**

```
package com.mrniamster.igbiome;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));


    }
}
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
    <style name="SplashScreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splashscreen</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**Androidmainfest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mrniamster.igbiome">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the Snapshot: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMhHQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

your Logo wont show Because You Move to Next Activity immediately with no pause.
try this in your `SplashScreen` Activity:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
            }
        }, 3000);
```

this make 3000 miliseconds (3 second) pause and next move to next activity.
**And** if xml not rendring preview try to Project Clean in Android Studio (Build/Clean Project) Or Do File/Invalidate Caches Restart.
if this didnt help, it may happened because of an error in your xml. re check your xml for any unexpected code.

Comment: please can u tell me where to paste your code ? Should i paste it after  public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

Answer (score 0):

Here is full code

```
package com.mrniamster.igbiome;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
        }
    }, 3000);



    }
}
```